# Splitting line with escaped separators in Python

Tags: python, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

TL; DR:

```
line = "one|two|three\|four\|five"
fields = line.split(whatever)
```

for what value of `whatever` does:

```
fields == ['one', 'two', 'three\|four\|five']
```

I have a file delimited by pipe characters. Some of the fields in that file also include pipes, escaped by a leading backslash.

For example, a single row of data in this file might have an array representation of `['one', 'two', 'three\|four\|five']`, and this will be represented in the file as `one|two|three\|four\|five`

I have no control over the file. I cannot preprocess the file. I *have* to do it in a single split.

I ultimately need to split each row of this file into the separate fields, but that leading backslash is proving to be all sorts of trouble. I initially tried using a negative look-ahead, but there's some sort of arcana surrounding python strings and double-escaped characters which I don't understand, and this is stopping me from figuring it out.

Explanation of the solution is appreciated but optional.

Comment: Write your own parser to account for escape sequences, a regex in Python `re` cannot handle it.

Comment: can you clarify what is your final expected output? `['one', 'two', 'three\|four\|five']` or `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']` ?

Comment: @spasic: the former.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex like

```
re.split(r'([^|]+[^\\])\|', line)
```

which will use a character group to specify anything except `\` followed by a `|` will be used to do the split

That will give an extra empty match at the beginning of the list, but hopefully you can work around that like

```
re.split(r'([^|]+[^\\])\|', line)[1:]
```

This is still subject to the parsing issues that Wiktor raised though, of course

Comment: What about `'one\\|two'`? It is [not matched](https://regex101.com/r/fM0dF6/1) while it should. When you have escape sequences, a regex will never be accurate.

Comment: Good point for sure, but if the requirement is to use `split` for some reason, this might be as close as one can get

Comment: I don't actually mind if @WiktorStribiżewc 's edge case isn't met. I don't need to escape the escape characters. I just need the split to not recognise `r'\|'` as a delimiter. Your (@EricRenouf 's) proposed solution won't work, as a naive split will also match the last character in the prior field, so you end up with `['on', 'tw', 'three\\|four\\|five']`. I've tried this in both a non-capturing group and a negative look-ahead, but the former captures it anyway, and the latter doesn't capture anything.

Comment: @RHill ah, oops, I withdraw my suggestion!

Comment: Well, it's the best suggestion to date. If I could just now somehow get it to not capture the `[^\\]`, it'd be perfect.

Comment: Also for a bit of background, this needs to be passed as a `sep` parameter for `pandas.read_csv()`, which handles separators with `split()`

Comment: @RHill I just updated it to hopefully fix the problem with the last letter getting grabbed, though I haven't yet thought about the `pandas` requirement

Comment: So I realised I was using look-aheads instead of look-behinds. `re.split(r'(?<!\\)\|', line)` works just fine, including in the pandas case. Curiously, `line.split(r'(?<!\\)\|')` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this :

```
[^\\]\|
```

where `[^\\]` match any caracter different of `\`.

Comment: No, this requires a parser. What about `'one\\|two'`? It is [not matched](https://regex101.com/r/fM0dF6/1) while it should.